# How to setting dpi for nodejs html-pdf

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, html-pdf

I'm using html-pdf to generate dynamic pdf file with html.
But pdf file is ugly, I think the reason is dpi not good.
I tried setting:

```
var options = {
  dpi: 96,
};

pdf.create(htmlTemplate, options).toStream(function(err, stream){
  if (err) {
    return res.end(err.stack)
  }

  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```

But no lucky. It still not work. I changed the value of dpi many times but pdf file looks the same.
Anyone can help me? Thank you!